# How to find third-party photo extensions

Tags: mac-appstore, photos.app

I want to find if there is any iphoto extension can share photos on google photos.

Therefore I check
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205245

it says

> Use the Mac App Store to find and install third-party extensions for Photos.

But I have no idea how to search App Store to find extension for photos.
Any idea?

Comment: Search for "google photos". If no Photos extension comes up it doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 2):

As of now there only a few extensions for Mac OS X Photos. Many more will be rolling out in the near future. So the extensions available right now are:

- BeFunky Express
- Intensify
- Tonality
- Noiseless
- Snapheal
- Affinity Photo
- Pixelmator
- DxO Optics Pro
- External Editors for Photos
- Picktorial
- Polarr
- HayPhotos
- Lochkamera

Answer (score 1):

I entered Photos extensions in the search bar of the Mac App Store and got 9 apps to come up (as of 01/03/2016). I'm not sure that all are even Photos extensions, either, but for sure, some of them are. I actually bought BeFunky Express for the teeth whitening and skin smoothing abilities. I also have some MacPhun apps that work as extensions: Snapheal CK, Intensity, Noiseless and Tonality. Pixelmator has a distort extension, but nothing more yet. And a newer app called Affinity Photo has some too, that are supposed to be pretty good. I haven't got that app yet so I don't know. But, I'm sure more extensions are on the way. Keep your eyes open for more…

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only way is to search for "Apple Photo Extensions" in the App Store search bar.  Unfortunately, it will bring up apps that are not extensions since the three words are pretty generic.  So far I can only find about a half dozen real extensions and quite honestly they are underwhelming.  I am beginning to think Apple's Photos move is a failure.  The new app and can't even do the basics that other photo editing software (including Apple's prior versions) can do.  Give me back Aperture with iCloud sync and I will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have just discovered that photos has a lot more in the way of editing features than I at first thought.  Adding options from the 'add' menu is a no-brainer, but I had totally missed the fine tuning options when you pull down the drop down menus in each edit option, and the hidden beauty of extending the tweaking range by pressing the Alt key is just diabolical.  Apple often does this, I find, make things very simple and assume if we are interested in going a little further that we will find the way ourselves.

The following article has been enlightening.
http://www.macworld.com/article/2965934/software-photography/the-hidden-editing-power-of-photos-for-os-x.html

Answer (score 0):

Search "Photos Extension" in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mac App Store, search for `appex:com.apple.photo-editing`.

You can also get to this by opening Photos, select a photo, click on Edit in the upper right, then click the "..." button, and select "More..." from the menu that appears. This will open the App Store listing of photo editing extensions.